# Can we add a message for future processing in MSMQ

Tags: msmq

I am trying to create a MSMQ solution and for certain message I want them to be processed after 6PM only so is there a way in MSMQ so that the message is processed in Future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the application to Peek the message first to read the property that lets you know it's a post-6pm message and act accordingly. If it's after 6pm, receive the message; if it isn't then Peek Next.

Comment: I was able to achieve this up to some extent .

Comment: @Piyush could you tell us what your solution was to delay the reception?

Comment: I added and Expected time filed in the message and then peeked that tag before executing .

Answer (score 5):

A queue is a first-in, first-out data structure. If your application needs to process some messages after 6 PM, move the messages to a different queue that is only processed after 6 PM.